# Filter Master Array by comparing against two other arrays

Tags: javascript, filtering, jquery-isotope

Ouch! My head hurts. Been working on this issue for hours and my brain is folding on itself.

Basically, Isotope is hiding or showing html elements on my page, and I need to hide or show the corresponding Google Maps markers on the embedded map in a very efficient manner (lots of Google Maps markers).

So... I have a MASTERARRAY[] full of objects.  Each object in the array has a unique id.

i.e. MASTERARRAY[i].id

This MASTERARRY[] also has a Google Maps marker object associated.

i.e. MASTERARRAY[i].marker

When Isotope filters the HTML elements on my page on my page, I push an object with the unique id to one of the following arrays:

1. ISOTOPEFILTER.resultsRemovedFromPage
2. ISOTOPEFILTER.resultsOnPageAfterFiltering

The code below will successfully REMOVE markers off my map by comparing the MASTERARRAY to ISOTOPEFILTER.resultsRemovedFromPage.  However, I have no idea how to efficiently have this function also show the Google Map markers who's IDs exist in the ISOTOPEFILTER.resultsOnPageAfterFiltering array.

```
function updateMap() {
    var hiddenMarkerCount = 0;

    for (i in ISOTOPEFILTER.resultsRemovedFromPage) {


            for (var j=0; j<MASTERARRAY.length; j++) {

            if (ISOTOPEFILTER.resultsRemovedFromPage[i].id == MASTERARRAY[j].id){
                hiddenMarkerCount++;
                MASTERARRAY[j].marker.setMap(null);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log("We have hidden"+hiddenMarkerCount+" markers");
}
```

Comment: I'm just typing `MASTERARRAY[]` to make sure it's in the comments as well, so everyone can see that it's actually uppercase, and it's called `MASTERARRAY[]` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the removed and included objects in an array, store them in an object keyed off the ID. Then you can do:

```
for (var j = 0; j < MASTERARRAY.length; j++) {
    if (ISOTOPEFILTER.resultsRemovedFromPage[MASTERARRAY[j].id]) {
        // Do stuff for removed items
    }
    if (ISOTOPFILTER.resultsOnPageAfterFiltering[MASTERARRAY[j].id]) {
        // Do stuff for included items
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Although, this technique required quite a bit of time to re-work the original code, the end result is blazing fast it's very it was very simple to implement once my objects were set.  Much appreciated!